# minimum of a set containing only equal numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

if i have a set **A = {3, 3, 3}**, what is the minimum of this set?

In general, what is the minimum (or the maximum) of a set containing only equal numbers?

Comment: Also worth noting that the *set* $A$ is just $\{3\}$.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you!

Comment: See [minimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_and_least_elements): "Let $(P,\leq)$ be a partially ordered set and $A\subseteq P$. Then $m\in A$ is a minimum of $A$ if for all $s\in A : m \leq s$."